Pywin32: Do SetWindowDisplayAffinity is not avaliable?
I am looking to implement windows api with python pywin32 then I want to hide a screenshot application. I have seen other options like using C/C++ language but I don't know, what do you recommend?
from win32gui import FindWindow
from ctypes import windll


while True:
    WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE = 0x00000011. 
    hwnd = FindWindow(None, 'Microsoft Edge')
    windll.user32.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE)

I tried that because I could not find the SetWindowDisplayAffinity function or if it is called the other way.
I am inexperienced in the windows api and I really want to know what I am doing wrong, could it be that python can not reach that level? or is not yet implemented that function in the library? or there are easier ways? I want to create a script for now but eventually I would like to continue scanning these functions.

See how to ask.

What you have done should work (check the return value), but it is best practice to fully specify the arguments and return types for ctypes function calls as the defaults often are not correct.
You also need to makes sure your window name is spelled correctly.  Using EnumWindows can help with that:
from win32gui import EnumWindows, GetWindowText
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

user32 = ct.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
SetWindowDisplayAffinity = user32.SetWindowDisplayAffinity
SetWindowDisplayAffinity.argtypes = w.HWND, w.DWORD
SetWindowDisplayAffinity.restype = w.BOOL

def callback(hwnd, param):
    s = GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if s:  # print handles of windows that have a name
        print(hwnd, s)

EnumWindows(callback, 0)

WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE = 0x00000011

hwnd = int(input('Enter a window handle from above: '))
if SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE):
    print('success')
else:
    print('failed')

